# match values across two list scala

Tags: scala, list

I am trying to find common values in two lists, for instance, I have a list of IDs in list1, and another list of IDs in list2. What is the most efficient way to output the matching elements as a separate list3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list1 intersect list2
```

should do the trick

example:

```
scala> val l1 = List(1,2,3,4,5)
l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val l2 = List(2,4,6)
l2: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)

scala> l1 intersect l2
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 4)
```